# How to add JButton to Canvas()? Or how to add JButton to Panel() and make the Panel() background as transparent?

Tags: java, linux, swing, user-interface, swt

How can I add a `JButton` to my `Canvas`?

```
public class mywindow extends Window
{
    private static final Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
    private JButton button;

    public mywindow
    {
        super(new Frame());
        button = new JButton("close");
        setLayout (new BorderLayout ());

        //Step 1 - failed
        add("North", canvas);
        canvas.setSize(300,300);
        canvas.setLocation(0,0);

        // button = new JButton(my, "close"); will not work
        // How can I add the button to the canvas?

        //Step 2 - works, but it gets the background color, instead of real transparency.
        //JPanel p = new JPanel(); p.setOpaque(false);
        //p.setSize(300,300); p.setLocation(0,0);
        //add("North", p);
        //p.add("Left", button);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you trying to mix AWT with Swing? Why not simply stick with an all-Swing GUI? And why are you making class fields static unnecessarily?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please don't mix [AWT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_Window_Toolkit) with [Swing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swing_%28Java%29). Today, Swing code is required [JPanel](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/panel.html). Sure, it is possible to mix AWT with Swing but with unexpected output to the GUI. For transparency, you have to look at *[How to Create Translucent and Shaped Windows](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/trans_shaped_windows.html)* and search for examples here.

EDIT: for the nicest and better output to the GUI check, how the [LayoutManagers](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) work.

Comment: Transparency link that you gave. Will it work with this? # java -version
java version "1.6.0_22"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.10.2) (fedora-58.1.10.2.fc15-i386)
OpenJDK Server VM (build 20.0-b11, mixed mode)

Comment: @89899.3K that really OS & OpenJDK rellated question, hard to talk, I cann't to give you answer for that, beacuse I only Win & Solaris admin, tutorial that link I posted is about Java SE Release 6 Update 10 API,